# Bootstrap modal-window is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a selection list, upon changing a selection, I need to show a message as popup, I used bootstrap modal but it is  not showing when I change selection

```js
function Selectionchange() {
  // document.getElementById('set-project').disabled=false;
  var opt = $("#gsb_tb option:selected").text();
  if (opt) {
    $("#mi-modal").modal('show');
    $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function() {
      $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
  }
  $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function() {
    $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select id="gsb_tb" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mi-modal" style="height: 45px; width: 78%; margin-left: 70px; padding-right: 90px; vertical-align: middle;" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" onchange="Selectionchange()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Project</option>
    <option value="370"> E-Card</option>
    <option value="278">B-Card</option>
    <option value="196">Z- Card</option>
     </select>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mi-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Have you got a new Project?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to close your `</select>` after options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several issues, but I think I mostly fixed it:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function() {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
    $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function() {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
    $("#gsb_tb").on("change", function() {
        var opt = $("#gsb_tb option:selected").text();
        if (opt) {
            $("#mi-modal").modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#gsb_tb {
    height: 45px;
    width: 78%;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 90px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<select id="gsb_tb" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Project</option>
    <option value="370">E-Card</option>
    <option value="278">B-Card</option>
    <option value="196">Z-Card</option>
</select>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mi-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Have you got a new Project?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Among other things you didn't close your `<select>`. I also removed the `data` attributes from it because they would make the popup show as soon as one clicked the dropdown, making it basically impossible to actually select an option.

Comment: thanks ,though I forgot to add 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> this style sheet.

Comment: Right, I added that. I also fixed the jQuery code; you were adding the button event handlers inside the `select`'s event handler.

Comment: yeah..I cropped the code from working code, so things got messed up while pasting.